# VSCode Create Dev Container - docker not found (worked before)

Tags: vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I seem to be unable to create any new dev containers on WSL2 Ubuntu (worked fine before) and I don't know how to debug this.

## Environment

- Windows 11
- WSL2 with Ubuntu distribution
- VSCode 1.75.1

  - Extension: Dev Containers 0.275.1 or 0.279.0 (no difference observed)
  - Extension: WSL 0.75.3
- Docker on Windows: none
- Docker on WSL Ubuntu: 20.10.22

## Scenario

- Open WSL2 Ubuntu terminal
- Go to desired development folder
- Start
  `code .`
- VSCode shows on Windows (Mentioning remote host "WSL:Ubuntu")
- Command: Dev Containers: **Create** dev container (e.g. Python container)
- Error shows:
  `Docker returned an error. Make sure the Docker daemon is running and select an option how to proceed.`
- Log shows:
  `Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}} [883 ms] findLocalWindowsExecutable: Exectuable 'docker' not found on PATH 'C:\Windows\system32;(...)'. [885 ms] Exectuable 'docker' not found on PATH 'C:\Windows\system32;(...)'. [890 ms] Docker returned an error code ENOENT, message: Exectuable 'docker' not found on PATH 'C:\Windows\system32;(...)'.`

## Already tried

- Previous creation of such dev containers on this environment worked fine.
- Executing the old dev containers on the current environment still works fine.

## Question

- I don't know where to get started to debug this. Probably something changed in my environment causing the creation of dev containers to fail, but I have no clue. I can't really reconstruct what would have changed to the setup.
- I didn't expect devcontainers to go and look for docker on my Windows path... I read about docker cli being used under the hood, but I never had docker on this Windows system, so it mustn't be essential in the WSL2 setup since it worked before.

Thanks,
Johan